# How do I count the amount of times a state is activated?

Tags: javascript, state, phaser-framework, state-machine

I'm working on playable combat with an npc using the Phaser 3 in js. I have state machines, each for the player and an npc.

I want to be able to count the amount of times a state is activated. I created a variable in my entity class, and then called the variable from a state (in this case, called a NPCWeakAttackState)

The weakAttackAmount code is written in my Player class which looks like this:

```
this.weakAttackAmount = 0
```

I built the state machine using this tutorial. [here](https://www.mkelly.me/blog/phaser-finite-state-machine/) It has worked fairly well.

I've had relative success in getting things to work, moving from state to state.
I figured I could try setting up a variable inside my entity class, called weakAttackAmount, that will be called into my states and incremented +1 each time the attack state is activated.
I could then use a conditional statement, if weakAttackAmount < 3 = then switch to the strong attack.

Problem is that, in my state code, it increments far more than I want it to. I only want it to increment once each time, whereas it instead increments multiple times.

The states work fine, but I can't increment a variable by one, and if I try, the variable goes well above 60 or 80.

I'm having some difficulty solving this problem. If anyone has any advice on state management, I'd really appreciate it. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated. I will be updating this post as much as I can. Thanks

So I edited my code to fit with Chris G advice. At the moment it looks like this.

```
export class NPCWeakAttackState extends State {
  enter(scene, npc) {
    npc.play("minotaur-weakattack", true)

    npc.weakAttackAmount = npc.weakAttackAmount + 1

    npc.on("animationupdate", (anim, frame) => {
        if (frame.textureFrame == 41) {
            npc.attackZone.x = npc.x + (npc.flipX ? -38 : 38);
            npc.attackZone.y = npc.y
            npc.attackZone.setSize(10, 10)
            scene.physics.world.enable(npc.attackZone)
        }
        if (frame.textureFrame == 42) {
            scene.physics.world.disable(npc.attackZone)
        }
        if (frame.textureFrame == 43) {
            this.stateMachine.transition("wait")
        }
    })
}
}
```

I'm still incrementing the value by 1 and its doubling it by 20. Each time the npc attacks its going from 20, 40, 60, and so on.

I just got it working.

```
export class NPCPrepareAttackState extends State {
enter(scene, npc, lastPos) {
    this.scene = scene
    this.npc = npc
    this.lastPos = lastPos
    this.amount = 0
}
execute(scene, npc) {
    scene.time.delayedCall(300, () => {
        scene.physics.moveTo(npc, this.lastPos.x, this.lastPos.y, 50)
        npc.play("minotaur-run", true)
        this.dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(this.lastPos.x, this.lastPos.y, npc.x, npc.y);
        if (this.dist < 60) {
            this.amount = this.amount + 1
            if (this.amount == 1) {
                this.stateMachine.transition("weakattack")
            }
        }
    })
}
}

 export class NPCWeakAttackState extends State {
enter(scene, npc) {
    npc.weakAttackAmount = npc.weakAttackAmount + 1

    npc.on("animationupdate", (anim, frame) => {
        if (frame.textureFrame == 41) {
            npc.attackZone.x = npc.x + (npc.flipX ? -38 : 38);
            npc.attackZone.y = npc.y
            npc.attackZone.setSize(10, 10)
            scene.physics.world.enable(npc.attackZone)
        }
        if (frame.textureFrame == 42) {
            scene.physics.world.disable(npc.attackZone)
        }
        if (frame.textureFrame == 43) {
            this.stateMachine.transition("wait")
        }
    })
}
execute(scene, npc) {
    npc.play("minotaur-weakattack", true)
}
}
```

Comment: You're increasing the value inside the `animationupdate` event, which looks like it gets called every frame, i.e. something like 60 times per second. This also points to a separate problem: unless `npc.on("blah", ...)` always overwrites previous "blah" event handlers, they'll accumulate. You should only have a single `npc.on("blah", ...)` line for each "blah", and use branching code inside the event handler.

Comment: In case it's not clear: think of running a bar, and hiring a bunch of new barkeepers each time happy hour begins or ends, rather than instructing your existing barkeeps *once* to charge differently based on whether it's currently happy hour or not. The only difference between these two handler functions is the sign of the 38; you can easily do `npc.attackZone.x = npc.x + (npc.flipX ? -38 : 38);` instead.

Comment: Right. That makes a lot of sense. I changed the code and updated the post to fit in with what you're referring to. I also changed it elsewhere in my code, because I was also calling the event twice somewhere else. I'm incrementing the value in the enter function, outside of the event. I'm unsure why this is happening. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If this is the only place where the value is increasing, you need to find out why the npc enters this state 20 times at a time.

Comment: I should add that, I'm using an overlap collision in the idle state for the attacks. I think its incrementing based on the length the collision takes place.

Comment: You could try implementing a mechanism that makes sure that the FSM never enters a state it's already in? Because that seems to be what's happening.

Comment: Yes! I got it to work. I used a variable that would count the first time the transition to weak attack is used. `this.amount = 0` and before the transition I incremented the number and used a conditional `this.amount = this.amount + 1` and `if (this.amount == 1) { this.stateMachine.transition("weakattack")}` I'm still unsure if this is the most optimal way of doing this, but it is working so far. I may post my progress in the future so people can take a look. Thanks for your help!